# No ordena datos con formato ##,##0.00 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ordenamiento, datagrid

tengo una aplicación que hace unos cálculos y los guardo en un datagridview, a una columna le doy el formato de moneda de esta manera: `Format(totalMarca, "##,##0.000")`
hasta ahí todo bien, pero intento ordenar los datos y no me los realiza. En la siguiente imagen muestra los datos después de ordenarlos de forma Ascendente. Pensé que estaba haciendo mal el algoritmo de ordenamiento pero ahora intento ordenar los datos con la opción por default del DataGridView y me sale el mismo detalle. Cabe aclarar que si no le doy formato a los datos si me los ordena correctamente.. Alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que al aplicar el formato, ya no son numeros, con lo que no puede ordenarles correctamente. Te sugiero que mantengas una columna oculta con los datos numericos y ordenes por ella.

Comment: Muy buena sugerencia, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resuelto el problema:**

Al momento de registrar la suma lo hago sin formato:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(marca, totalMarca)
```

y ya en el momento de interactuar con el formulario donde contiene el dataGridView hago el ordenamiento:

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

y al último doy formato.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "$ #,##0.00"
```